# sed and regular expression: unexpected replacement pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to use a small bash script using sed to append a string, but I do not seem to be able to make it work.
I want to append a string to another string pattern:

Strings in input file:

```
Xabc
Xdef
```

Desired output:

```
XabcZ
XdefZ
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
instring="$2"
sed -r "s/${instring}/${instring}Z/g" $1
```

Where $1 is the file name and $2 is the string pattern I am looking for

Then I run the script:

bash script.test.sh test.txt X

output:

```
XZabc
XZdef
```

As expected.
but if I use regular expressions:

```
bash script.test.sh test.txt X...
```

All I get is:

```
X...Z
X...Z
```

So obviously it is not reading it correctly in the replacement part of the command. Smae thing if I use X[a-z09] (but there may be "_" in my strings, I want to include those as well). I had a look at several previous similar topics, but I do not seem able to implement any of the solutions correctly (bear with a newbie...). Thank you for your kind help.

**EDIT: After receiving the answers** from Glenn Jackman (accepted solution) and RavinderSingh13, I would like to clarify two important points for whoever is having a similar issue:

1) Glenn Jackman solution did not work because I needed to convert the text file from DOS to Unix. I did it with `dos2unix` , but for some reason did not work (maybe forgot to overwrite the output to the old file?). I later did it using `sed -i 's/\r$//' test.txt` ; that solved the issue, and Glenn's solution now works. having a dos-formatted text file has been the source of many trouble, for me at least.

2) I probably did not make clear that I only wanted to target specific lines in the input files; my example only has target strings, but the actual file has strings that I do not want to edit. That was probably the misunderstanding occurred with RavinderSingh13's script, which actually works, but targets every single line.
Hope this can help future readers. Thank you, Stackers, you saved the day once again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have (`sed -r "s/${instring}/${instring}Z/g" $1`) uses the variable as a **pattern** on the left-hand side and as **plain text** on the right-hand side.

What you want to do is:

```
sed -r "s/${instring}/&Z/g" $1
# ....................^
```

where the `&` marker is replaced by *whatever text the pattern matched*. In the documentation for [The `s` Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command):

> [T]he *replacement* can contain unescaped `&` characters which reference the whole matched portion of the pattern space.

Comment: Thank you, I tried: the "Z" is appended as a prefix, rather than a suffix and it is actually overwritten to whatever character precedes  my target string.

Comment: Does your file have CRLF line endings? If yes, use `dos2unix` or `sed 's/\r$//'`

Comment: OK, I did dos2linux, thank you for the advice. The replacement is still not working right: if I use  "X*" it matches any line; if I use "X..." it does not change anything...

Comment: Hi, Glen, it actually works if I use "X[a-z][a-z][a-z]" instead of the 3 dots. Is there any way I can  shorten it? If I use "X*" the Z gets  inserted after every character

Comment: OK, not knowing what to do, I tried to convert it from dos to unix again, using the sed solution this time. Now your solution works using "X.*" as pattern. Thank you for all the help and time spent on the issue!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: In case you need to pass a regex to script then following may help, where my previous solution was only appending a character to last of the line.

```
cat script.ksh
value="$2"
sed  "s/$value/&Z/"  "$1"
```

After running the script:

```
./script.ksh X.*
XabcZ
XdefZ
```

After seeing OP's comment to match everything which starts from either small letter or capital letter run script in following style then.

```
./script.ksh [A-Za-z]+*
```

---

---

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
cat script.ksh
value="$2"
sed "s/$/$value/" "$1"
```

After running script I am getting following output on terminal too.

```
./script.ksh Input_file Z
XabcZ
XdefZ
```

You could use `sed -i` option in above code in case you want to save output into Input_file itself too.

Comment: I'd just move the quoting to the ends of the string: `"s/$value/&Z/"`

Comment: OK, if I use "X.*" as a pattern, it overwrites it as a prefix to to whatever character was before the target string. If I use "X*" as a pattern, it still inserts Z as a prefix, but without overwriting the preceding character. Also, it does it for every line, rather than just matching strings

Comment: @madmaxthc, yes right there is a reason for it. `X*` means look for only capital letters which are NOT there so it inserts `Z` after `X` but when we give `X.*` after `X` one more small letter is counted now so `.*` covers all small letters now and thus `Z` comes at last. Please do let me know if this is clear now?

Comment: @madmaxthc, in that case try to run script like `./file8294274264876.ksh [A-Za-z]+*` and let me know then?

Comment: Uh... it's still working on every single line, rather than just the target pattern

Comment: What do you mean? It will perform a substitution on all lines which match the pattern; if you pass in a pattern which matches all lines, then that's what it will do (and it's hard to imagine what you want otherwise).

Comment: What I mean is that I do not want to change every single line. That is why the second variable is a pattern; not all lines need to be changed, only the ones where "X" is found. Z is the replacement, but only where X is present. The script as it is now uses "$2" as a replacement on every line

Comment: That is a good point though, I should have made the sample input clearer, by adding extra non-target lines, my bad. The way it is it can lead to misunderstanding on the desired output. I appreciate the help and time, Ravinder, thank you